# How to copy a line of text in terminal using keyboard only?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am coding in the terminal of VS Code. When I manage to make a line of code that I like, I would like to copy it and paste to the editor. How can I copy the current line from the terminal with keyboard only without using mouse?

Edit1: I am using windows

Comment: This is probably dependent on operating system Linux, Windows or OsX

Comment: Did you try holding Shift key and using arrow keys to select the line and just use ctrl + c ???

Comment: Shift+A does not select text but adds more nonsense to the line

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 11 with PowerShell console this works for me:

Press arrow up to get the line of code that you want. Then press CTRL+A to select it and CTRL+C to copy it into clipboard. Paste it with CTRL+V.

Comment: Ctrl+A selects everything in console.

Comment: @user3914505 Not for me, but I guess this depends on what operating system and console you are on. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Allow users to do copy paste in the integrated terminal using ctrl+c, ctrl+v.

In addition to ctrl + shift + v you can use ctrl + shift + c to Merge-Copy. And ctrl + shift + x to Merge-Cut. Select clipboard to paste ( ctrl + alt + v ). Paste and cycle through clipboard items ( ctrl + shift + v ).

Comment: ctrl+c, ctrl+v does indeed copy and paste to the terminal, but I would like to copy/cut from terminal and paste to the editor. Paste to the editor does not work.

Comment: To get to your clipboard history at any time, press Windows logo key + V. You can also paste and pin frequently used items by choosing an individual item from your clipboard menu. You can use clipboard.

Comment: In cmd, for copy select what you want to copy ad press Enter. Enter is a shortcut to copy in cmd and Ctrl+V in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

This was one of the first search results for the opposite: copy from the editor to the terminal using only the keyboard.

There is a command to run the selected text in the active terminal: `@command:workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText` and you can add a Keybinding to it.

Open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) and type `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts`. There you define a command.

The configuration is saved as json.
On Windows it's `C:/Users/my_user/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/keybindings.json`:

```
[
    // Run current line in terminal
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+t",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !findInputFocussed && !jupyter.ownsSelection && !notebookEditorFocused && !replaceInputFocussed"
    },

    // Toggle focus between terminal and editor
    {
        "key": "ctrl+t ctrl+t",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+t ctrl+t",
        "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    }
]
```

In this example I'm using `ctrl+shift+alt+t` to send the current line to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution! Select area to copy Ctrl+Shift+A, Ctrl+Shift +C, xclip -selection c > yourfile.txt, nano yourfile.txt”